# What is a word for the option to attend or host an event?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for the option to attend or host an event?

I have a form label and do not know what to title it. Under the label are two options. The options are to host or attend an event.

---

**Lable for options**

- Hosting
- Attending

Comment: Naming is off-topic, so I would recommend editing the question to include a sentence instead of a **label**. But you may consider using **Status**.

Comment: Hosting or Attending is wordy. Event Role is not bad I may go with that. Thanks. Post as an answer and I will give you a 1+.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about naming..

Comment: @Hank ok well where do I enter questions about naming?

Comment: I can't accurately recommend a place because I don't know one for sure. If you reword your question, it can be on-topic. Just word it as you are looking for a word to fill a blank, with a sample sentence, and providing a mock definition for the word you are searching for. Just edit the question to make it not about naming something. The [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists what is on- and off-topic.

Comment: Well, you'd be a "participant". So that's something.

Comment: Could be “Level of Participation” of “Participation Level”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Event Role, short and sweet.